# How to reduce the size of a video recorded with Camstudio for uploading to YouTube?

Tags: youtube, upload, video-conversion, camstudio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I reduce the size of a huge MP4 video?](https://superuser.com/questions/4244/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-huge-mp4-video)

I have recorded a less than 1 minute video using Camstudio, and it yielded a 600MB AVI file.

What is the simplest way for uploading it to YouTube? What is the best program I could use to convert and compress my video before uploading it?

Comment: Which video conversion software have you tried? Don't tell me you couldn't find one ;)

Comment: Related: [How do I reduce the size of a 4 gigabyte mp4 video to less than 1 gigabyte?](http://superuser.com/questions/4244/how-do-i-reduce-the-size-of-a-4-gigabyte-mp4-video-to-less-than-1-gigabyte)

Comment: @techie007 The answers apply perfectly to this problem, therefore voting to close as a dupe. Thanks for finding!

Comment: BTW, you can change the video compressor in Camstudio directly. Depending on how powerful your machine is, you may be able to record to xvid or even x264 directly.