# ffmpeg reducing frame rate doesn't decrease file size

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-encoding, h.264

My goal is to reduce the overall file size of a video without quality loss. The source video is at 30fps with keyframes every 90 frames. For our purposes we only need the video to be at 3fps and keyframes every 300 frames my assumption is transcoding the video to this will reduce the overall video size.

This ffmpeg command re-encodes the source video to `out.mp4`

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 out.mp4
```

This command reduces the fps and increases the GOP.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=300:scenecut=0 fps=fps=3 out.mp4
```

My question is why does the output from both commands result in the same video size?

Comment: The 2nd command appears to have syntax error, the correct command would be: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=300:scenecut=0 -filter:v fps=fps=3 out.mp4`. When run, `out.mp4` will indeed be smaller and has a lower [frame rate](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/ChangingFrameRate) (tested with ffmpeg 4.2.2).

Answer (score 0):

As per [ckujau’s comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1532132/ffmpeg-reducing-frame-rate-doesnt-decrease-file-size#comment2324166_1532132), the original command is missing the `-filter:v` option:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=300:scenecut=0 fps=fps=3 out.mp4
```

It should be placed before `fps=fps=3` like this:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=300:scenecut=0 -filter:v fps=fps=3 out.mp4
```

Posting this here since ckujau’s comment is clearly the answer, but they only posted it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/38380/470616) and the linked, [detailed answer](https://superuser.com/a/4252/677283) finally pointed me in the right direction: for me, reducing FPS didn't do much if I didn't also tweak the bitrate (or, similarly, the [constant rate factor](https://slhck.info/video/2017/02/24/crf-guide.html)).

*Increasing* the CRF *decreases* the quality. A value of 28 is on the lower end quality-wise for x264:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 28 -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=300:scenecut=0 -filter:v fps=fps=3 out.mp4
```

Similarly, you can specify the target bitrate:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -b:v 450k -vcodec libx264 -x264-params keyint=300:scenecut=0 -filter:v fps=fps=3 out.mp4
```

Both of these methods led to a >2x decrease in file size.